# Как узнать id категории?

Tags: php, yii2

Пишу парсер, который получает информацию с сайта. Получается такой массив:

```
$array(
    [category]=>'Loren ipsum'
    [description]=>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.'
    [name]=>'За словесными горами'
    [desc]=>'Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.'
    [cat]=>'Lorem ipsum'
);
```

Есть модели `category` и `post` следующего содержания:

```
category ->id,name, description; 
post ->id,name,description,id_category
```

Соответственно в контроллере запись в базу буду проводить так:

```
$category= new Category();
$post =new Post();
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
  $category->name = $array['category'];
  $category->description=$array['description'];
  $category->save();
  $post->name=$array['name'];
  $post->description=$array['desc'];
}
```

Как мне узнать `id` только что созданной вот этой категории `$category` для того что бы записать в `id_category` поста?

Comment: `$category->save();

$inserted_id = $category->id_category;` поможет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то есть вы имеете в виду  $category->save(); $post=$category->id ?

Comment: Ну вы указали `id_category` поэтому я так написал... я не знаю где у вас какие поля...и  `$post` у вас модель, так что, скорее `$post->чего-то там = $category->id;` ....видимо `$post->id_category = $category->id;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский   да теперь вы написали как у меня. А то что сатегория только что создана, а $category->id это AUTO_INCREMENT это ни чего ?

Comment: Да ничего......вообще стандартная функция `create` выглядит `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }` .......как мы видим если сохранилось что-то в БД - редирект на страницу с только что созданными данными.... автоинкремент - самое оно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в обще если получится (а это будет завтра я вам отпишусь) что бы вы ответ оформляли.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Алексей вот составил такой кодforeach($informayion["genre"] as $title){
            if(!in_array($title,$categorys)){
                $thecategory= new Category(['name_category'=>$title]);
                $thecategory->save();
                $theIdcat[]=$thecategory->id;
            }
        } пишет ошибку  Setting unknown property: common\models\Category:: и ругается на это  $theIdcat[]=$thecategory->id;

Comment: Это нужно смотреть глубжЕе... что у вас в таблице и пр.... тем более вы говорили что в цикле `save` это плохой код, а сейчас его и делаете.... к тому-же, надо проверять `if ($thecategory->save()) {...` Может запрос не выполнился и вернулась ошибка, а вы не проверяете и пытаетесь что-то взять

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39296/discussion-between-sergalas-and--).